# csv extraction from a multi-level xml

Tags: csv, xslt

I'm trying to extract csv from xml. The leaf element names from the entire xml form the header line and all the corresponding text values are the data rows. If a given leaf element is not present in a node, then print blank value. Below sample xml and output would explain what I'm trying to do.

Input XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<itemList>
    <item>
        <userID>123</userID>
        <userName>ABC</userName>
        <orders SINGLE="Y">
            <order>
                <orderID>0000377T</orderID>
                <orderType>online</orderType>
            </order>
        </orders>
        <details SINGLE="Y">
            <detail>
                <color>black</color>
                <make>pluto</make>
            </detail>
        </details>
        <addresses SINGLE="N">
            <address>
                <addrID>000111NR</addrID>
                <addrName>HOME</addrName>
            </address>
            <address>
                <addrID>000111ST</addrID>
                <addrName>OFFICE</addrName>
                <comment>HQ</comment>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </item>
    <item>
        <userID>456</userID>
        <userName>DEF</userName>
        <orders SINGLE="Y">
            <order>
                <orderID>0000377T</orderID>
                <orderType>phone</orderType>
            </order>
        </orders>
        <details SINGLE="Y">
            <detail>
                <color>red</color>
            </detail>
        </details>
        <addresses SINGLE="N">
            <address>
                <addrID>000222NR</addrID>
                <addrName>HOME</addrName>
            </address>
            <address>
                <delivery>am</delivery>
                <addrID>000222ST</addrID>
                <addrName>OFFICE</addrName>
            </address>
        </addresses>
    </item>
</itemList>
```

Expected output:

```
userID,userName,orderID,orderType,color,make,addrID,addrName,addrID,addrName,comment,delivery
123,ABC,0000377T,online,black,pluto,000111NR,HOME,000111ST,OFFICE,HQ,
456,DEF,0000377T,phone,red,,000222NR,HOME,000222ST,OFFICE,,am
```

### XSLT which I am able to frame so far:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
      <xsl:output method="text" />
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
      <xsl:variable name="newLine" select="'&#xA;'" />
      <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','" />
      <xsl:key name="field" match="//*[not(*)]" use="local-name()" />
      <xsl:variable name="allFields" select="//*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', local-name())[1])]" />
      <xsl:template match="/">
<!-- print the header line -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
          <xsl:value-of select="local-name()" />
          <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newLine" />
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
          <xsl:value-of select="$newLine" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*[not(*)]" mode="pass" />
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="*" mode="pass">
        <xsl:if test="position()!=1">
          <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
        <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
          <xsl:value-of select="$this[local-name() = local-name(current())]" />
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Output I'm getting with above XSLT when executed against above shown xml:

userID,userName,orderID,orderType,color,make,addrID,addrName,comment,delivery

123,ABC,0000377T,online,black,pluto,000111NR,HOME,000111ST,OFFICE,HQ

456,DEF,0000377T,phone,red,000222NR,HOME,am,000222ST,OFFICE

The problem in this result is:
1.no blank space is being print for a non-existent leaf element. 
2.header line contains only one set of addrID, addrName whereas my input xml contains 2 sets.
3.an empty line is printed in the output after every row even though I used strip-space at the start of XSLT.

Can you please help to achieve the desired output as shown above under Expected output..? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why is `delivery` the last column in the header line although the `item` which has a `delivery` descendant leaf element has further leaf element after that `delivery` element?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: that is because *addrID* and *addrName* elements present after the *delivery* element are already included into the header line while processing the first *item* node.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Any clues on this please..?

Comment: Sorry, I have not managed to understand what defines a column and their order, obviously if you want to allow duplicate column names then it doesn't make sense to use a key to eliminate them so I wonder why you have used that key on the local name.

Comment: @MartinHonnen : to keep it simple, the aim is that the above shown multi-level xml has to be converted into csv. All the tag names present in all the 'item' tags form the csv header and while populating the data rows if the tag name is not present, then populate blank value. So that the output is a well formed csv with equal number of fields in each row exactly under the respective header field.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: From my previous comment, please understand all the tag names=all the leaf element names.

Comment: @MartinHonnen: And my idea of using xsl:key is to first collect all the leaf element names appearing anywhere in the document so that the values for the same can be extracted from each 'item' node. Looking at it now, seems like it will not help me to achieve the desired result. Do I need to create separate keys for address[1] and address[2]..? I'm not sure. This is where I need some clue to proceed further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with some discrepancy in your solution.

You write the title row as all field names **without** repetitions.

But your sample data show, that one item can contain **several**
leaf nodes (data fields) with **the same name** (not just 1).
So a data row can include more items than the title row and you get a mess,
as you don't know, to which title relates particular field.

So we must start with a proper way to assemble the **title row**.

To find out how many times each field name should be repeated, you should for each field name:

- count how many times this field occurs in each *item*,
- take maximum from these numbers.

As a sesult we get *reptNums* array - repetition numbers for respective fields from *allFields*.

Let's move on to the way how to assemble each **data row**.

The following procedure should be performed for each *item*.

For each field name:

- get leaf nodes with this name, but only these which have the current *item* as an ancestor,
- for each such node print its value and a comma,
- print extra empty values (actually only commas) if the number of real values was less than the respective *reptNum*.

The text assembled this way includes a comma after the last field, so it is assembled in a variable (*row*)
and then actual output cuts off this last char.

The whole solution is included below (in XSLT version 2).

I tested it on http://xsltransform.net, using *Saxon HE* engine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Global variables -->
  <xsl:variable name="newLine" select="'&#xA;'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="comma" select="','"/>

  <!-- Field names (without repetitions) -->
  <xsl:key name="field" match="//*[not(*)]" use="local-name()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="allFields" select="//*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', local-name())[1])]" />
  <!-- # of field names -->
  <xsl:variable name="fieldCnt" select="count($allFields)"/>
  <!-- Generated IDs for items -->
  <xsl:variable name="itemIds" select="//item/generate-id()"/>
  <!-- Repetition numbers for field names -->
  <xsl:variable name="reptNums" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
      <!-- Get fields for current name -->
      <xsl:variable name="fields" select="key('field', local-name())"/>
      <!-- How many times does this field occur in each item? -->
      <xsl:variable name="nums" as="xs:integer*">
        <xsl:for-each select="$itemIds">
          <xsl:variable name="itemId" select="."/>
          <xsl:value-of select="count($fields[generate-id(ancestor::item)=$itemId])"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <!-- Return max value -->
      <xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(max($nums))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Create array of header items -->
    <xsl:variable name="headers" as="xs:string*">
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $fieldCnt">
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="."/>
        <!-- Name of the current field -->
        <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="$allFields[$index][1]/local-name()"/>
        <!-- Repeat the field name respective number of times -->
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $reptNums[$index]">
          <xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Print the header line -->
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join($headers,',')"/>
    <!-- Actually - proces items -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- Terminate the previous row -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$newLine"/>
    <!-- Generate data row for current item -->
    <!-- Generated ID -->
    <xsl:variable name="itemId" select="generate-id()"/>
    <!-- Assemble the output row -->
    <xsl:variable name="row">
      <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
        <!-- Name of the current field -->
        <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select=".[1]/local-name()"/>
        <!-- Fields for the current name, but only from this item -->
        <xsl:variable name="fields"
          select="key('field', $fieldName)[generate-id(ancestor::item)=$itemId]"/>
        <!-- Write values found -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Which reptNum take for the current field? -->
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>
        <!-- Write extra commas -->
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer($reptNums[$index] - count($fields))">
          <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Print the row, but without the last comma -->
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($row, 1, string-length($row) - 1)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and solution that is as much generic as possible. The XSLT given by you has produced the correct wanted result. I'll accept your answer shortly. As I've been working on XSLT 1.0 only so far, I'm trying to understand your XSLT 2.0 code. I understood how the header line is being framed now.

Comment: 1. What I am unable to get is how the data rows are getting populated correctly under the respective header column. Inside the variable 'row', what does `<xsl:variable name="fields" select="key('field', $fieldName)[generate-id(ancestor::item)=$itemId]"/>` do..? 2. Why are the extra commas being printed finally at the last for-each loop inside 'row' variable..?

Comment: 3. I applied the transformation (using java command line with saxon9he.jar) against the input xml of around 21MB size containing 5k+ 'item' nodes and the execution is going on close to 1 hr for now. Is it because of lot of processing logic going on in this xslt..?

Comment: 4. Finally, is there a way to achieve this in XSLT 1.0..? I'm thinking in the lines of extracting all the unique xpaths across all 'item' nodes into a variable and executing each of these xpaths for each of the elements of 'item' nodes. Would it be possible..? The header line can still be extracted manually or through a separate xslt as it would be a one-time activity.

Comment: Understood from your explanation. I've accepted your answer. A new requirement came up that in my input xml, under each `item` tag contains one more element named `reviews` (sibling of addresses) that contains multiple `review` elements which in turn contains several leaf elements. All these reviews/review/* leaf elements should appear under a single column in the output with header name say 'allReviews'. These values under the single column should be separated by a different delimiter (say pipe, |) other than comma.

Comment: Let me try this as an exercise for myself. I believe this `reviews` element should be processed in a separate template match.

Answer (score 0):

In comments to my 1st answer you asked about instruction:

```
<xsl:variable name="fields"
  select="key('field', $fieldName)[generate-id(ancestor::item)=$itemId]"/>
```

Let's start with used variables:

- fieldName - name of the current field (e.g. userName),
- itemId - generated ID for the current item.

Now let's examine particular parts, on the example of *userName* field:

`key('field', $fieldName)` - From key with name *fields* read sequence of all fields saved under *userName*.

But this sequence contains *userName* nodes from **all** items, so we have to narrow down this selection
with a predicate:

```
[generate-id(ancestor::item)=$itemId]
```

Let's examine each part:

- `ancestor::item` - returns *item* node containing this *userName*,
- `generate-id(...)` - get node ID generated for this *item*,
- `=$itemId` - we require that the above ID be equal to ID for the current item.

As a result, we get (as the comment before states): Fields for the current name 
e.g. *userName*), but **only from this item**.

Then, in the following for-each loop, these fields are written (with a comma after each field).

**Why does the script print extra commas:**

Consider an example of *addrID* field.

There are e.g. max **two** *addrIDs* in each *item*, so the title row contains 2 *addrID* headings.

In order to be in agreement with the heading row, for each item we must output just **two** values.

But if e.g. an item contained only 1 *addrID*, then:

- we would print this (1 and only) *addrID* found in this item,
- the 2-nd value was absent, so we would have to print an "empty value" - only a comma.

Otherwise under the 2-nd *addrID* heading you would get a value for the next field name, in this case *addrName*.

**Regarding your questions # 3 and 4, I can suggest:**

XSLT is likely to operate slowly on big volume data.
My advice is that you changed from XSLT 1 to XSLT 2.

Remember that XSLT 1 has smaller set of functions.

E.g. `string-join` function was introduced just in XSLT 2.
Of course instead of `string-join` you can write `for-each` loop with conditional printout of a comma (don't print after the last value).

But then this code would operate even slower, probably beyond the threshold of acceptance.

So there is a risk, that you put much effort to rewrite this script in XSLT 1, just to find out that it operates too slowly and you still have to return to XSLT 2.

**One more advice concerning big data:**

Try this script on a small sample, then on increasingly bigger samples.

This way you will have an assesment of how long it would operate on bigger input data.

## Edit concerning additional requirement concerning *allReviews* field

The change turned out not very complicated.

The first thing to change is how to create the title row.

Two corrections are required:

- Create key *fields* without *review* nodes (the predicate contains now *and ./local-name()!='review'*).
- Append a comma and *allReviews* to the header row.

Now, in *item* template, the loop for all fields still gathers field values but **without *review* nodes**, as *allFields* does not contain this name.

*Review* fields are added after all "regular" fields.
I made use of your note that *reviews* tag is a sibling of *addresses*, in other words, a direct child of *item*.
This way I used an explicit XPath, what is likely to operate quicker (a general performance hint is to avoid "//" in XPaths).

And the last change: As there is no need to cut off any comma, the output can be written directly to the output file (no need to use any intermediate variable).

See below for the complete solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Global variables -->
  <xsl:variable name="newLine" select="'&#xA;'"/>
  <xsl:variable name="comma" select="','"/>
  <xsl:variable name="pipe" select="'|'"/>

  <!-- Create index of leaf fields, without reviews -->
  <xsl:key name="field" match="//*[not(*) and ./local-name()!='review']" use="local-name()"/>
  <!-- Field names, without repetitions -->
  <xsl:variable name="allFields" select="//*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', local-name())[1])]" />
  <!-- # of field names -->
  <xsl:variable name="fieldCnt" select="count($allFields)"/>
  <!-- Generated IDs for items -->
  <xsl:variable name="itemIds" select="//item/generate-id()"/>
  <!-- Repetition numbers for field names -->
  <xsl:variable name="reptNums" as="xs:integer*">
    <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
      <!-- Get fields for current name -->
      <xsl:variable name="fields" select="key('field', local-name())"/>
      <!-- How many times does this field occur in each item? -->
      <xsl:variable name="nums" as="xs:integer*">
        <xsl:for-each select="$itemIds">
          <xsl:variable name="itemId" select="."/>
          <xsl:value-of select="count($fields[generate-id(ancestor::item)=$itemId])"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <!-- Return max value -->
      <xsl:value-of select="max($nums)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Create array of header items -->
    <xsl:variable name="headers" as="xs:string*">
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $fieldCnt">
        <xsl:variable name="index" select="."/>
        <!-- Name of the current field -->
        <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="$allFields[$index][1]/local-name()"/>
        <!-- Repeat the field name respective number of times -->
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to $reptNums[$index]">
          <xsl:value-of select="$fieldName"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- Print the header line ... -->
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join($headers,',')"/>
    <!-- ... with custom field name at the end -->
    <xsl:text>,allReviews</xsl:text>
    <!-- Actually - proces items -->
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <!-- Terminate the previous row -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$newLine"/>
    <!-- Generated ID for the current item -->
    <xsl:variable name="itemId" select="generate-id()"/>
    <!-- Write data row for the current item -->
    <!-- Part 1: "Regular" fields -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
      <!-- Name of the current field -->
      <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="local-name()"/>
      <!-- Fields for the current name, but only from this item -->
      <xsl:variable name="fields"
        select="key('field', $fieldName)[generate-id(ancestor::item)=$itemId]"/>
      <!-- Write values found -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$fields">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <!-- Which reptNum take for the current field? -->
      <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()"/>
      <!-- Write extra commas -->
      <xsl:for-each select="1 to $reptNums[$index] - count($fields)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$comma"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- Part 2: Reviews -->
    <xsl:value-of select="string-join(reviews/review, $pipe)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Edit concerning reviews defined as *reviews/review/**

Sorry, I missed that `review` leaf tags are one level deeper.

The required corrections are again quite simple:

1. Change the instruction that creates *field* key to:

   ```
   <xsl:key name="field" match="//*[not(*) and not(ancestor::reviews)]"
       use="local-name()"/>
   ```

   Actually you change only `match` attribute. Now the key includes:

   - leaf nodes (`//*[not(*)`, as before),
   - but excluding descendants of `reviews` tag (`not(ancestor::reviews)`).
2. Change instruction creating *Part 2* of content row to:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="string-join(reviews//*[not(*)], $pipe)"/>
   ```

   Actually the change involved only the 1st argument of `string-join` function.

Now `allReviews` is created from all leaf nodes - descendants of `reviews` (in the current `item`).

Note that now you can have also a `review` without subordinate leaf nodes, such as `<review>xxx</review>`.

Comment: Thanks for the revised code @Valdi_Bo. The `reviews` tag looks like `<reviews>
            <review>
                <comment1>c1</comment1>
                <comment2>c2</comment2>
                <comment3>c3</comment3>
            </review>
             <review>
                <comment4>c4</comment4>
                <comment5>c5</comment5>
                <comment6>c6</comment6>
            </review>
        </reviews>`
        and the above revised XSLT produces the output same like before i.e. all the comment1,comment2,comment3 appears in the header line still.

Comment: Thank you @Valdi_Bo, now it's fine. I have one more doubt from your XSLT code: inside `xsl:template match="item"` we're looping through $fields and getting its value. As the current context node is `item` and $fields contain the leaf elements at any depth, how does xsl:value-of extracts the values for each of the element names in $fields..? Is there something specific to XSLT 2.0 going on here..?

Comment: Note the instruction under comment _Fields for the current name, but only from this item_.
`key('field', $fieldName)` finds all fields for the current name (for all items), but the following predicate narrows down this selection to the current item.
It requires that: 1. Id generated for item to which the field belongs (`generate-id(ancestor::item)`), 2. Must be equal (_=_), 3. To the item id (`$itemId`) generated at the beginning of this template.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thank you.